# Storing uri in SQLite database, can't open PDF from uri because of permissions

Tags: android, sqlite, pdf, permissions

I am making a very simple app to display PDF's. I want to organise the pdf's in a library of sorts and so am storing the details (document name and URI) in an SQLite database. The issue I am having is, when trying to open the pdf from the URI, I get this error message...

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.externalstorage.ExternalStorageProvider uri content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3APictures%2F2002.pdf from pid=29624, uid=10179 requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
```

I have tried add the following to the code where I add the pdf's to the database...

```
myFileIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
        myFileIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

Doing this proved that my code for opening the pdf works, as it does enable me to open it, but it doesn't seem persistent and will eventually cause the error again.

I am very new to android dev and dev in general, so I could be approaching this all wrong... so my questions are...Is there a way to store a URI in the database and then open a PDF using that stored URI? Is there a way to get around the permissions issue with my method of opening pdfs?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried add the following to the code where I add the pdf's to the database...

Neither of those flags are appropriate here. Those are for the *provider* of the content to say what access rights you can get.

> Is there a way to store a URI in the database and then open a PDF using that stored URI?

If `myFileIntent` is for `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, then call `takePersistableUriPermission()` on a `ContentResolver` when you get the result `Uri`. This will accomplish what appears to be what you were trying to do with those flags: get long-term rights to the content identified by the `Uri`.